# What is the name for taxi-passenger design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

Imagine a taxi stand. Sometimes there is a queue of taxi cabs, sometimes a queue of passengers. A thread pool is a perfect example of implementation of such a pattern: sometimes worker threads wait in line for tasks, and sometimes tasks wait for worker threads.

More generally, this pattern can be applied for any pool of resources and accompanying queue of requests to that resources.

What is the name of such a pattern? Dispatcher? Distributor? I am thinking how to name a class which implements such a pool.

Comment: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool

Comment: @jaco0646 - not exactly: it has only  resource pool, and no explicit request queue. Instead, there is only queue of threads which attempt to make a request.

Answer (score 0):

[Queue-Based Load Leveling pattern](http://java-design-patterns.com/blog/queue-load-leveling/) seems to fit the description.

Comment: not exactly - it has only request queue, and says nothing about how resource pool is organized.